# How to connect two networks

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I have one Encoder network that learns values [as in this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHAsE.png), where theta1 and theta2 are learnable parameters. Then I need to create a Processor network that needs the `mu_v` values in order to compute the values [as in this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPawt.png). The loss is computed based on the values computed by the second network, so the first network is not trained when I should concatenate it to the second one.

My question is how can I concatenate the two networks, i.e. how can I use the values `mu_v` in the second network?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language or libraries you are using, but connecting two networks can be done mathematically

To concatenate the networks, you can simply adjust your model. Rather than keeping the two networks separate, how about you create your own network model with the first network feeding into the second?